# Restrict the UIDatePicker control based on type, say (Adult, Child, Infant) Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uidatepicker

Am trying to restrict the UIDatePicker control based on type, say (Adult, Child, Infant). Below is what am currently doing to call the DatePicker

```
cell.leftDetailTextField.inputView=[self customDatePickerView];

-(UIDatePicker *)customDatePickerView{
    NSLog (@"Date picker called");
    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    [datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
    //datePicker.maximumDate=[NSDate date];  // to prevent future date selection:
    
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setYear:-90];
    NSDate *minDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate  options:0];
    [comps setYear:-12];
    NSDate *maxDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate  options:0];
    
    datePicker.minimumDate = minDate;
    datePicker.maximumDate = maxDate;
    
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    return datePicker;
}
```

How can I dynamically pass a value to this method call. I need to pass Adult(val 1), Children(Val 2), Infant (val 3)

Comment: You mean ```-(UIDatePicker *)customDatePickerView:(NSUInteger)val{...``` and then you use ```val``` for your logic and you call it e.g. ```[cell customDatePickerView:1]```?

Comment: Yes, it answers my question.

Comment: Great thanks for feedback. Remember what normally appears as e.g. ```int func( long a, NSString * b, UIColor * c )``` in Objective-C will be e.g. ```- ( int ) funcWithIndex:( long ) a stringValue:( NSString * ) b color:( UIColor * ) c``` and you'd call it as ```[object funcWithIndex:a stringValue:b color:c]``` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(UIDatePicker *)customDatePickerView:(NSInteger)val{
    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    [datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
    
    //datePicker.maximumDate=[NSDate date];  // to prevent future date selection:
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    NSDate *minDate, *maxDate;
    switch (val) {
        case 1: // Adult
                [comps setYear:-90];
                minDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate  options:0];
                [comps setYear:-12];
                maxDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate  options:0];
            break;
        case 2: // Child
                [comps setYear:-12];
                minDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate  options:0];
                [comps setYear:-2];
                maxDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate  options:0];
            break;
        case 3: // Infant
                [comps setYear:-2];
                minDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate  options:0];
                [comps setYear:-0];
                maxDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate  options:0];
            break;
            
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    datePicker.minimumDate = minDate;
    datePicker.maximumDate = maxDate;
    
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    return datePicker;
}

- (void) dateChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender{
    UIDatePicker *datePicker=(UIDatePicker *)sender;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
    self.activeTextField.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's it.